# How to extend the sensible area around active area (hyperlinks) in Firefox?

Tags: user-interface, firefox, hyperlink, touchscreen

At which level in Firefox the active zone around active areas (text and image hyperlinks) is defined ? I would like to experiment ways to extend them to ease the use of touchscreens for the web...

Answer (score 1):

After discussions with some Mozilla folks, I tried to implement a solution using javascript with a Greasemonkey script available at http://www.splitted-desktop.com/~flepied/touchscreen/touchscreen.user.js. It tries to find the nearest link when you click on something that is not active.

Answer (score 0):

The only way I know of is via the CSS property [`padding`](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_padding.asp).

Comment: There is no way to do it at the browser level ? I don't want to do it at the site level...

Comment: You could do some browser targeting - but why are you just targeting Firefox?

Comment: Dominic, 

I'm looking for a solution to create a kiosk like system with a touchscreen and my browser of choice is Firefox. Will it work with another browser ?

Answer (score 0):

This is mostly not browser-specific, but determined by the layout information (in html or css). Basically, the area that the "link" element occupies is the clickable area. If you need a larger area, you have to make the element larger .. increase the text that is clickable, increase the font-size, increase padding (which might look strange).

Comment: In fact I want to build a special browser with such capability and so I'm looking for ways to do it modifying Firefox...

Comment: You could add you own CSS on the client side and enlarge padding, font-sizes etc. Client-side CSS would theoretically override the server provide, but I have no idea how stable that is. Also, try to use the different zoom-levels (Ctrl-+ to enlarge) in FireFox and see if that helps you any.